# Undo string to binary in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, binary, unpack

I have a code to transform from string to binary:

```
> s = "AnatomÃ­a SegÃºn Grey"
=> "AnatomÃ­a SegÃºn Grey"

> s.unpack("a*").first
=> "Anatom\xC3\x83\xC2\xADa Seg\xC3\x83\xC2\xBAn Grey"
```

How can I get the original string (undo the `unpack`)?

Comment: There is a pack method but I'm not sure what argument you need to feed it to reverse the unpacking..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion is equivalent to:

```
s = "AnatomÃ­a SegÃºn Grey"
#=> "AnatomÃ­a SegÃºn Grey"

s.force_encoding('BINARY')
#=> "Anatom\xC3\x83\xC2\xADa Seg\xC3\x83\xC2\xBAn Grey"
```

It can be "reversed" via: (you might have to adjust the `'UTF-8'` part)

```
s.force_encoding('UTF-8')
#=> "AnatomÃ­a SegÃºn Grey"
```

[`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) doesn't change the string, it just defines how the bytes are interpreted.

To fix the string, you probably have to call [`encode`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-encode) in addition:

```
"AnatomÃ­a SegÃºn Grey".encode('ISO-8859-1').force_encoding('UTF-8')
#=> "Anatomía Según Grey"
```

Comment: As I just checked, there is also `encode` method that will in fact change the string.

Comment: @FranMartinez are you trying to fix a broken string? I've added an example.